# can someone help me solve q4 from smo junior

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive integers satisfying

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+1) \quad\text{and}\quad  x+y+z=2022$$

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two distinct solutions for $x$, what is the value of $x_1+x_2$?

I'm stuck, I don't even know where to begin

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+1)\iff (x-y)^2+z^2=2$

Comment: Try with the second equation, $ ( x + y + z )^2 = 2022^2 $

Comment: Nope! The previous comment has given you the answer.

Comment: what does SMO stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given y,z, 
$$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + z^2 - 2 = 0$$ 
is a quadric equation in x.
Use the quadric formula from completing the square to find two solutions for x.
Adding those two solutions eliminates the radicals to give a very simple answer.